# Determine scripting language from string

Tags: php, scripting, syntax-highlighting

I've written a generic file system viewer in php and I'd like to add context highlighting.  [Geshi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geshi/files/geshi/GeSHi%201.0.8.10/) looks good for this, but appears to require me to send in the language I want to highlight the code in.

Any existing methods on how to determine the scripting language of a given file by contents and/or location?

I have the mime type from:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
$mime_type = @finfo_file($finfo, $full_path );
```

That lets me know it's text at least (I allow download of non text too).

I'm thinking that parsing the bang line/file extension or looking for simple tags like php would get me a good chunk of the way for things like perl/shell scripts/php.

I also have the path to the file, as these files are coming directly off the source servers so path based rules may work for things like /etc/httpd/conf.d/*, /etc/passwd.

Perfect accuracy isn't really a problem as I'll allow the user to override the language used for the syntax.  I just want to provide a low overhead educated guess to start with without writing this from scratch.

One other caveat.  Some of these files can be > 150mb so I'd like to only read part of the file although I could just turn off this feature for large files if needed.

Comment: Why do you not look at the file's extension?

Answer (score 1):

If you can call out to an external program, try the Linux [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command.

Comment: Yes I can.  That gives me bang line parsing.  Good start.

Comment: You know I had dismissed the capibilities of 'file' as nothing more than what mime-type would give me but, I just tested this and it's pretty good.  Actually .. fails to detect perl scripts as perl on a windows mounted fs.

Comment: Do the misidentifed perl scripts start with a bang line?

Comment: Yes, but they are like #!perl

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised noone pointed me to [prettify.js](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) from google code.  It will probably do everything I need it to, client side.